# Adding Microsoft teams as an activity in Moodle

Tags: module, microsoft-teams, moodle

Moodle don't have a module for Microsoft teams but I need to add Microsoft teams as an activity
i tried to use it as an External tool according to this link :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/lti/teams-classes-meetings-with-moodle?view=o365-worldwide

is there any other way to achieve what i want ?

Comment: Could you please confirm if you are developing a Teams app? Based on the description it does not seem like a Teams app development question. Could you please elaborate a little?

Comment: Could you please share above asked details?